# What is the best way to overcome MBR limitations for a Mac/Mac/Windows triple boot?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, partitioning

Most of the question is in the title, but here's a little explanation. I have a MacBook Pro with a 512 GB SSD inside of it. On that SSD I have a Mac partition running OSX 10.9, another Mac partition running 10.6 (for legacy software), and a block of unused space into which I intend to install Windows 7. However, because of the EFI partitions that are automatically generated, the disk appears to have 4 logical partitions, and because of this, the MBR limitation of Windows 7 prevents it from installing.

I'd really like to NOT reformat the entire drive and copy all of my stuff back onto it just to get Windows into that empty space.

Comment: The simplest solution.  If your system is creating EFI partitions then you should be using GPT partitions.  There exists methods to convert to GPT without data loss.

Comment: You need to force the Windows 7 disk to boot in EFI mode instead of BIOS mode so that it uses GPT partitions instead of MBR partitions.

Comment: @DarthAndroid, EFI mode does not work on all models (basically only on Airs) and even in cases where it does, Win7 has a harder time of it than Win8 does, and sound drivers in particular don't seem to work right either. EFI booting Windows is a useful experiment, but not something I would consider practical.

Answer (score 2):

You need to dump the (hidden) recovery partition.  It's conveniently at the end of the drive, but that's what is using your last MBR partition entry.

Note that you cannot use the BootCamp Assistant in your configuration, as it is an unsupported configuration.  No biggie, though.  Here's how to do it without BootCamp:

1. Using Disk Utility, expand your 10.6 partition to take up the entire rest of the drive. This is needed for the next step. There can be no free space between the the last partition and the recovery partition.
2. Open up a Terminal window and type `diskutil list`. It *should* show you four partitions:
   Your EFI partition (disk0s1).
   Your 10.9 partition (disk0s2).
   Your 10.6 partition (disk0s3).
   And your recovery partition (disk0s4), which does not show in Disk Utility.
3. At the command prompt, type the following command exactly as shown:
   `diskutil mergePartitions JHFS+ Untitled disk0s3 disk0s4`
   This command should delete the recovery partition and expand your 10.6 partition to fill the rest of the disk.
4. In Disk Utility, reconfigure your partitions the way you want.  Shrink your 10.6 partition back down to make room for the Win7 partition. Click the plus sign to add a new partition in the empty space and **select MS-DOS (FAT) as the partition type**.  Then hit the Apply button to make the changes.
   **NOTE:** Even though you're probably going to reformat it NTFS, selecting FAT in this step is important because that's what makes Disk Utility create the hybrid MBR.
5. Insert the Windows 7 DVD, and `Option`+Boot your Mac.
   **Do not select EFI** as Darth suggested in the comments.  EFI+Win7+MacBook is a mixed bag.  Some models don't support it at all, and those that do often have driver issues. Either way, it's totally unsupported by Apple.
6. Install Windows 7 normally at this point.  Remember to reformat that Fat32 partition to NTFS.  Also, because you didn't use the BootCamp Assistant, you must download the BootCamp drivers from Apple's web site and put them on a flash drive so you can then install it in Windows when you're done.

At this point, you now have a triple-boot system.  Note that your partition table is now totally full.  You cannot add any more partitions -- Even if you shrink one of your OS X partitions.  It will break your Windows installation.